# Layout is Broken when I update the Table View Height Constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

when I'm trying to update my table view height constraint constant it causes a bug in the view.
What I am doing wrong?

---

```
  func setupViewHeight() {
    // prepare the animator first and keep a reference to it
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, timingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(animationCurve: .linear))
    animator.addAnimations {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    // at some other point in time we change the constraints and call the animator
    self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(self.previousClinics.count) * self.cellHeight

    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    animator.startAnimation()

    self.tableView.reloadData()
  }
```

---

[Wrapper View Subview Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyhDr.png)

[Wrapper View Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwJdy.png)

[Buggy View in Action (video)](https://youtu.be/iR2lbLUwI6c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one thing -> change tableview height constraint priority to 100 and try to remove all fixed height of cell.
Hope it'll help you.

**Try this one.It's work perfectly for me.**

```
let cellHeight = 100.0
var cell : tableCell?
let detailArr : [UIColor] = [.red,.yellow,.black,.blue]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.changeTableHeight()
}

func changeTableHeight()
{
    let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, timingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(animationCurve: .linear))
    animator.addAnimations {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    tableviewHeight.constant = CGFloat(Double(detailArr.count) * self.cellHeight)

    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    animator.startAnimation()

    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

[image: Cell image with constraint]

[image: Table view with fix height]

[image: Table with orange background color and height as per total number of cell]

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately, Any other suggestion? I tried almost everything!